# How can I grab the only part of a string that matches a regular expression?

Tags: php, html, regex

If I had an HTML input of `123Smith456%$@#***()NotSmith`, for example, and I just wanted the alphabetical characters, how could I use a regular expression to just match and grab the `Smith` and put it in a variable?

Comment: as states in the question, if you use `/Smith/` as a regex it will match Smith, please be more clear about the input and output that you want

Comment: @Koala I've edited the question, How would I just grab the alphabetical characters to give me `Smith`.

Comment: Play with regex on a site like https://regex101.com/r/CbP5Af/1 (I've even started you off!) Read the PHP manual, `preg_match()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php and `preg_replace()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: You need really big / sticky hands,  or tape....  Them matches can be slippery.

Comment: `[A-Za-z]+` will match alphabetical characters [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/CbP5Af/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE option in the preg_match function.

Your expression needs to be wrapped in () to group the matches you wish to capture. You can have any number of groups, so you can capture various parts and store them in various variables.

For example:

```
$string = '123Smith456%$@#***()NotSmith';

preg_match('/(Smith)/', $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

print_r($matches);
```

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Smith
            [1] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Smith
            [1] => 3
        )

)
```

If you are looking to extract all the actual "words" you could do something like this:

```
$string = '123Smith456%$@#***()NotSmith';

preg_match('/([A-Za-z]+)/', $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

print_r($matches);
```

This will match all occurrences of anything has characters in the range of A-Z or a-z which occur once or more. Which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Smith
                    [1] => 3
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => NotSmith
                    [1] => 20
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Smith
                    [1] => 3
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => NotSmith
                    [1] => 20
                )

        )

)
```

See: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php